# Use Faker to fill table without knowing table structure

Tags: mysql, yii, yii2

Can I use (and if yes -- then how) [Yii2 Faker](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-faker-index.html) to fill entire table (all columns) with random data for `n` records without knowing table structure? Can Faker check schema and do this for me or do I have to write my own code, that will use it in this scenario?

I want, for example to test, how large my database will become, when I feed it with let's say millions of records. Since my database contains many tables and each table has different structure, I would like to use something automated rather than writing my own code for each table and each structure.

Is this possible with Faker or possibly any other extension to Yii2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Gii, it goes through all the columns on a table and does some things. You can also figure out that columns are foreign keys and get data from other tables.

I do not know of anything that does this for you automatically it is doable.

1 thing, you have to give it an order to fill in the tables, it will not work unless you fill the tables in a specific way especially with the foreign keys.

Comment: I know how to code such logic, since we have access to tables' schema and we can iterate through it to make sure, we fill all columns with correct type random data, etc. I was going to write such thing myself, even without using Gii example (however, thanks for a good advice). I only wanted to make myself sure, that I'm not reinventing the wheel again. Since you made me sure, that no such automated thing exists, then I need to start working myself. Thanks.

Comment: I personally do not know of 1 :) there might be. Make it a git repository, I will try to help with it.